# Timeline bar for graph

Tags: graphs, wpf

I have a graph with nodes that have a time property. I was wondering if there is a control that displays a timeline according to the nodes.

Something like the below picture:

[image: graph]

For example in the picture the first node’s time is 12th December 2006 at 15:00 and the timeline control at top shows the same time.

more information:

-the location of nodes is fixed, i can't reposition them .

-I display graph on a layout control (such as grid or canvas) and i want another control to display timebar.

-the intervals of time bar aren't same.

-it's so much better if your suggestion be the wpf control.

thanks